# Parse Issue in Xcode 6.1 - “Expected a type”

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Problem with Xcode:
Compilation failed and I got some errors (see picture below).

[image]

Comment: who's array, a user defined class, a typo for NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know what `Array` is. Either you actually mean `NSArray *` or it's one of your types: then you need to add the corresponding `#import` statement. If it's a class, you can also use the forward declaration `@class Array;`, but you then need to refer to it as `Array *` since Objective-C only supports pointers to object instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mean NSArray (hopefully), and Array is a class, import your class and don't forget * mark with Array (or NSArray).